# Python: Comparing 2 CSV's and pull data over if a certain cell matches

Tags: python, csv

File A:

```
id,desc,name
12345,blah blah blah,jsmith
6789,yada yada yada,ckast
54321,yum yum yum,jpetersen
```

File B:

```
key,id
AB-873,6789
CF-395,54321
HG-713,12345
```

What I want to do is take look at each line in File A, see if the `id` column matches an `id` column in File B, and if it does copy over the 'name' cell into File B. So in the end, File B would look like:

```
AB-873,6789,ckast
CF-395,54321,jpetersen
HG-713,12345,jsmith
```

I know the 'csv' Python module can read individual lines but I'm at a loss on where to go from there. Thanks!

Comment: Are the files of a size where they will both fit into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple code, this code works for you:

```
a_lines = open('FileA', 'r').readlines()[1:]
b_lines = open('FileB', 'r').readlines()[1:]
file_result = open('result', 'w')

# Read content of FileA to a table (list of lists)
a_table = []
for l in a_lines:
    a_table.append([w.strip() for w in l.split(',')])

# Read content of FileB in a dictionary.
# The 'id' field as dictionary key for simple look-up.
b_dict = {}
for l in b_lines:
    words = l.split(',')
    b_dict[words[1].strip()] = words[0].strip()

# Do the actual work and save result.
for row in a_table:
    if row[0] in b_dict:
        file_result.write(b_dict[row[0]] + ',' + row[0] + ',')
        file_result.write(row[2] + '\n')
```

I tested it with your sample.

Answer (score 0):

With [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), you could do something like:

```
import csv

with open(fn1) as fa, open(fn2) as fb:
    r1, r2=map(csv.reader, (fa, fb))
    a_header, b_header=map(next, (r1, r2))
    data_a, data_b=map(lambda header: {k:list() for k in header}, 
                           (a_header, b_header))
    for line in r1:
        for k, v in zip(a_header, line):
            data_a[k].append(v)
    for line in r2:
        for k, v in zip(b_header, line):
            data_b[k].append(v)

b_header+=['name']        
data_b['name']=[]        
for e in data_b['id']:
    try:
        v=data_a['name'][data_a['id'].index(e)]
    except ValueError:
        v=None    
    data_b['name'].append(v)    

with open(fn3, 'w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)  
    writer.writerow([e for e in b_header])  
    idx=0
    while True:
        try:
            writer.writerow([data_b[key][idx] for key in b_header])
            idx+=1
        except IndexError:
            break
```